# "to" + infinitive vs. just infinitive vs. gerund after the phrase "verb for"

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, descriptive-grammar

The Spanish verb *contar* translates to "to count". Which of the following would be a better way to express this in formal writing:

> 1. *Contar* is the Spanish verb for count.
> 2. *Contar* is the Spanish verb for "to count".
> 3. *Contar* is the Spanish verb for counting.

I know a safer option is to just say, "*Contar* is the Spanish verb that means 'to count'." but I'd prefer to pick one from the above three options.

Comment: Three is right out, it doesn't even make sense. Two is the best. One is okayish, but "count" must be in quotes. For that matter, in all three, and the rest of your post, *contar* must be set in quotes or italics. [Use–mention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and reference...could you please post this as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: It depends on whether you think your audience will know what a verb is. If you say "_Contar_ is the Spanish verb 'count'", the _to_ complementizer is unnecessary, because you're specifying a verb. But your audience may not know that, and may recognize a verb only when it's cited with a _to_ in front of it. Author's choice -- only the author knows who it's being written for and to.

Comment: @JohnLawler Please post your comment as an answer so I could accept it and close the thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As John Lawler observes in a comment above, the degree of specificity appropriate to your sentence depends on your audience's level of knowledge about language and the terminology used to describe it. In addition, you are constrained by your own preferences about word choice and word order. If it were my sentence, I would use one of the following wordings, depending on context and on how familiar my audience was with terminology related to parts of speech:

> ***Simple:*** In Spanish, *contar* means "to count." ***Or:*** *Contar* in Spanish means "to count."
>
> ***Slightly more detailed:*** The Spanish verb *contar* means to count. ***Or:*** *Contar*, a Spanish verb, means "to count."
>
> ***Slightly more detailed still:*** In Spanish, the infinitive *contar* mean "to count." ***Or:*** *Contar*, a Spanish infinitive, means "to count."

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

As "contar" is the infinitive, Contar is the Spanish verb for "to count" would be better. But can you contar conmigo?

Answer (score 0):

*Contar* is the Spanish verb for "to count" (or "count").

Comment: This does not contribute anything new to what was already said, and indeed asked. Please see our [**Help Center** to learn how to write a good answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Unless you edit this answer to meet those standards, it will likely be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer "Spanish contar means to count".